# How to format methods in a class

Tags: java, coding-style, formatting

I have nearly about 12 methods in my class. My doubt is, is there any formatting style like the called method has to be written next to the caller method" Is there any standard that maximum methods per class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest reading **Robert C. Martin's** thoughts on this in his book **Clean Code**. He writes that a class should be readable as an article or a page of a book, so you preferable keep methods close to which they call into. Of course it is impossible to keep everything this way but you can head towards it. This eliminates the need to browse big sources frequently. For maximum methods Fowler has some rules also but it really depends on the class, but: keep methods and classes as small as possible.

Comment: Thanks for referring me this book http://www.e-reading-lib.com/bookreader.php/134601/Martin_-_Clean_Code_-_A_Handbook_of_Agile_Software_Craftsmanship.pdf  Are there any such books Could you suggest.

Comment: I mistyped the author but - Martin Fowler has great books also in the refactoring topic too. Also there are some other recommended titles mentioned in Clean code too.

Comment: Do you know correct name for GangofFour design patterns book? I couldn't get!

Comment: Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software

Comment: I thought the name of the book itself is "GoF" ! Is there Any specific edition for Java? @ragatskynet

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to keep calling and called methods next to each other, most obviously due to the fact that they can be in different classes.

There are no standards that would say "you can't have over 20 methods in a class", since it's not something that you can standardize (or rather it wouldn't make sense). With experience you'll learn to see if a class has too many methods (one indication would be that a class seems to be responsible for 2 different things, in which case you'd refactor the class into 2 different classes).

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, 12 methods are too many for a class, I think you should think it over, if there are too many methods, maybe they are contradict to object-oriented thoughts. If you are OK with a specific language, you can get to know some design models such as [**MVC**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), maybe that will give you some ideas.